# JHipster: Filtering entities with criteria - intended Angular client-side approach

Tags: angular, jhipster

I've recently started using [JHipster](http://www.jhipster.tech/) - thanks to the maintainers for this fantastic project!

In the current version of JHipster (4.10.2 at the time of writing), entities can have filtering enabled via the entity sub-generator, or by including `filter EntityName` and `service EntityName with serviceClass` to the project's JDL file. This produces a Spring project in which the `getAllEntities()` method in the `EntityNameResource` class takes a `Criteria` argument constructed from the URL `GET` params.

This works out-of-the box with the Swagger UI generated for the endpoint, and the queries issued by this UI demonstrate that the back-end expects each criterion to be in the form of a `GET` parameter key-value pair; this is consistent with [the 4.10.2 Filtering docs](http://www.jhipster.tech/documentation-archive/v4.10.2/entities-filtering/).

However, I wonderd whether there is an intended approach to using this from a front-end Angular project that I have missed, beyond making appropriate modifications oneself to construct a conforming URL.

The front-end services use the static function `createRequestOption(req)` (exported from `app/shared/model/request-util.ts`) to populate the `GET` parameters for paging and sorting. This function also expects that the passed-in `req` object may have a `query` attribute; initially, I thought that populating this parameter was the intended way to use the back-end filtration.

However, the implementation of `createRequestOption(req)` currently places the value of `req.query` into a `GET` parameter called `query`; i.e this does not produce the query format expected by the back-end, which expects a separate `GET` parameter per criterion.

The solution which I have used is to modify `createRequestOption(req)` to expect an array of key-value pair objects instead of `req.query` (I've called it `req.criteria`), and add these to the `URLSearchParams`'s array (it has to be the array, not the map, since there may be multiple parameters with the same key, e.g. `name.in=Megatron&name.in=Optimus`).

So I've changed:

```
params.set('query', req.query);
```

to:

```
if (req.criteria && req.criteria.length > 0) {
    req.criteria.forEach((criterion) => {
        params.append(criterion.key, criterion.value);
    });
}
```

...with component code populating the array along the lines of the following:

```
let criteria = [
    {key: 'name.equals', value: 'Optimus'},
    {key: 'power.equals', value: '10'}
];

this.entityService.query({
    page: this.page - 1,
    size: this.itemsPerPage,
    sort: this.sort(),
    criteria
});
```

I just created an example of this working in practice with some form fields filtering a test single-entity monolithic app (currently equals queries only) with this approach in GitLab [here](https://gitlab.com/ImperfectClone/jhipster-filter-criteria-test).

So, my questions are:

- Have I missed the intended way of doing this with the current JHipster version?
- What is the intended use of `req.query` in the current implementation of `request-utils.ts`?
- Is this area expected to change in upcoming versions? For example, might front-end search fields be automatically generated in the way in which ElasticSearch-enabled apps do (but for each entity attribute)?

Many thanks.

Comment: You might want to ping @gzsombor on twitter so that he answers here as he is the author of this feature.

Comment: You should correct the typo:
>>>> if (req.crieria && req.crieria.length > 0)
It's criteria

Comment: @JonathasPacífico oh yeah that's true, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've done very similar thing in my projects too, in my solution the criteria is used like this:

```
let criteria = {
   'name.equals' : 'Optimus',
   'power.equals' : '10'
};
```

Currently, I work on an 'auto-complete' field, which will use the criteria, and has the necessary extension to the request-util.ts. Here:
https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/6618

And yes, I think, that parameters of that 'query' method is bit confusing, it need to be be simplified a bit.

Maybe, we can generate a client side version of the 'EntityCriteria.java', as 'entity-criteria.ts', but I'm not sure. There is a constant push against new features, and less code, which I could understand.

Comment: This is very helpful thank you @Renszarv - especially seeing the planned implementation from the linked PR, as I'm keen we use as much of the out-of-the-box functionality of JHipster as possible, so now we can build to the upcoming `createRequestOption (req?: any, queryParams?: any)` version.

I notice the new implementation still uses the Map to store the criteria in - `params.set(key, queryParams[key]);` rather than `append`, though: isn't this a problem, as some criteria have the same key, i.e. `name.in=Optimus&name.in=Megatron`?

Comment: Can this filtering be done based on the defined roles? For example: I have two distinct roles, who need to access the same data model. However, one role has less credentials for seeing all the attributes, so in its case, the entity's attributes need to be filtered on client-side.